# How can i get the disk details in csv format in windows server using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0

Hi all I want to get details in below format

```
Hostname    Drive_0              Drive_1             Drive_2

Name        C: 99.899227142334   d: 99.899227142334  e: 99.899227142334
```

I can get this detail using below script but this works on PowerShell 3.0
how can I change to execute on PowerShell 2.0

```
$result = @()
$obj = new-object PSobject
$server = hostname
$obj |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Hostname" -Value $server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$z = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Logicaldisk -Filter 'DriveType=3' | Select-Object -Property DeviceID,  @{LABEL='TotalSize';EXPRESSION={$_.Size/1GB}}

$z3 = $z.DeviceID
$z4 = $z.TotalSize
$i = 0
foreach($z3 in $z3){
 $z1 = $z.DeviceID[$i]
 $z2 = $z.TotalSize[$i]
    $zx = "$z1" + ": $z2"

      $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Drive_$i" -Value $zx -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

$i++
  }
   $result+=$obj
     $result | Export-Csv  "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Result.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What errors are you getting when running on PowerShell 2.0?

Comment: Do you by chance get this error on machine running 2.0 that only have one disk? `Unable to index into an object of type System.Double`

Comment: perfect matt.. the same error i am getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your code to the below. It's a bit neater and sorts out your loops and limits so you don't need to manage them

```powershell
$result = @()
$obj = new-object PSobject
$server = hostname
$obj |Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Hostname" -Value $server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$z = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Logicaldisk -Filter 'DriveType=3' | Select-Object -Property DeviceID,  @{LABEL='TotalSize';EXPRESSION={$_.Size/1GB}}

$i = 0
$z | % {
  $z1 = $_.DeviceID
  $z2 = $_.TotalSize
  $zx = "$z1" + ": $z2"
  $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Drive_$i" -Value $zx 
  $i++
}
$result+=$obj
$result | Export-Csv  "$env:userprofile\Desktop\Result.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I also removed the `-ErrorAction` off the `Add-Member` as you should try and handle anything that crops up yourself, but add it back if you feel the need to.